# HQL correlated subquery uses group by produces subquery returns more than 1 row MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Video Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "video")    
public class Video implements Serializable{
     ....
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "video",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @Getter
     @Setter
     private List<ActivityLog> activityLogs;
}
```

Second Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity_log")
public class ActivityLog implments Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "action")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private ActivityLogEnum action;

    @Column(name = "ctime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date ctime;
    @JoinColumn(name = "account", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Account account;
    @JoinColumn(name = "video", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Video video;
}
```

I want to select **videos** with **activitylogs** grouped by **action** field
So I tried :

```
select v,(select al from ActivityLog al where al.video.id=v.id group by al.action order by al.id desc) as al from Video v
```

Then faced that correlated subquery produces : `Subquery returns more than 1 row MySQL`

Tried also `left join`

```
select v from Video v left join (select al from ActivityLog al where al.video.id=v.id group by al.id,al.action order by al.id desc)
```

Same problem

Also tried `join fetch` but was stuck in how to write group by

So how to make this in Hibernate

activity_log table :

[image]

Action value would be one of 3 mentioned in following enum :

```
public enum ActivityLogEnum {

    TRANSLATION_SESSION_STARTED("Session Start Time"), TRANSLATION_APPROVAL("Approval Start Time"), TRANSLATION_REJECTION("Rejection Start Time");
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String label;

    private ActivityLogEnum(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

}
```

I want to group by the action desc so that multiple actions won't be fetched just last unque 3 types actions can be fetched.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query doesn't make much sense. group by is only useful where you have aggregate functions (like sum(), count(), avg(), etc.). What are you trying to achieve. Give concrete examples.

Comment: Post example table with data and the results you need, make text tables from them don't post a image..

Comment: @JBNizet  Updated post

Comment: @RaymondNijland Updated post sorry text version won't be in a good format to post